# Figure information when MouseDown event

Tags: rascal

Is there any possibility to get extra information about the Figure, which was clicked, when dealing with an onMouseDown event?  I mean, extra variables that can be included when the Figure was constructed.  This, to be used in a list comprehension.  Like, for example, when constructing a Treemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnMouseDown event takes a closure as a parameter, which in principle can capture any variable of the scope in which is was created.

Here is the example code from the documentation at http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Figure/Properties/onMouseDown/onMouseDown.html, extended with "extra information":

```
import vis::KeySym;
s = "";
s2 = "";
extraInformation = "some additional info about the b box"; // definition of extra information
b = box(text(str () { return s; }),
    fillColor("red"),
    onMouseDown(bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers) {
        s = "<butnr>" + extraInformation; // later use of extra information
        return true;
    }));
```

It is important to understand that the closure/lambda captures bindings to the *variables*, not their *values*. So the contents of the `extraInformation` variable changes if some other code which captures the same variable changes it. In the example, this happens for the `s` variable, but not for the `extraInformation` variable because nobody assigns into it after the initial declaration.

So, watch out for binding loop variables from `for` loops and comprehensions: they always end up having the contents of the final loop iteration. To work around this, introduce an extra variable like so:

```
boxes = [box(..., onMouseDown(..., bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers) { use of var })) | x <- elements, var := x];
```

or like so:

```
boxes = for (x <- elements) {
   var = x;
   append box(..., onMouseDown(..., bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers) { use of var }));
}
```

If we would have used `x` instead of `var` in the closure all your boxes would have the same value for `x`, which is the last element of `elements`. W

Comment: Thank you very much.  I got stuck with always getting the contents of the last iteration.